# CoordinatorLayout with Toolbar and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm using the layout below, The `CoordinatorLayout` holds inside it `AppBarLayout` (With `Toolbar` and `TabLayout` inside it) and a placeholder `RelativeLayout`, so I could add and replace fragments on it.

I'm experiencing margin errors, the fragments I add on the RelativeLayout will always over expand beyond the bottom of the screen (in the amount similar to the size of the `AppBarLayout` height), I've tried setting it's height to `wrap_content` and `match_parent`, in both cases it goes overboard.

if I remove the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from the `RelativeLayout` the top of it will be under the `AppBarLayout` which is also not the desired outcome.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


       <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you give a better example? That `RelativeLayout` does not do anything and has a height of technically `0` because of `wrap_content` unless you are doing something with it programmatically. If you are going to use it as a `containter`, use a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: I'm putting a fragment on it, doing a fragment transaction and providing the id of the RelativeLayout, i've also tried using FrameLayout same result.

Comment: It is obvious you got this from Chris Banes's example: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/include_list_viewpager.xml. Notice his `ViewPager` uses `match_parent`?

Comment: Are you setting the height for the inserted fragment to match_parent? I did a test with your layout and it all seemed to work correctly.

Comment: Yes, my code is based on that example. The problems starts when you change from ViewPager to FrameLayout/RelativeLayout. match_parent doesn't have an effect on the issue.

Comment: @bkurzius - Yes, the fragment root layout is set to match_parent

Comment: The issue has been solved: had a recyclerview in the fragment, but it was't the latest revision of it, when updating to com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0 the issue has been solved

Comment: @Calc -- great to hear - you should add it as an answer so others can benefit from it :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out the problem on showing fragment below toolbar when using the coordinator layout. The problem in my case is:

[In this image it shows the Fragment is overlapped by Toolbar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaT3F.png)

Now just put your AppBarLayout and FrameLayout inside LinearLayout like below,

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainappbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now your problem is solved. And it will be like this.

[The final image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu8sU.png)

Comment: `AppBarLayout` should be a direct child of a `CoordinatorLayout`. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

Answer (score 2):

You will also see this issue if you have a ScrollView inside the fragment. So make sure you use a NestedScrollView instead:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: What about LinearLayout? I'm having a similar issue with it.

Comment: Can you wrap it in a NestedScrollView?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Changing `RelativeLayout` to `FrameLayout` with parameter `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` solved my problem.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved by updating the recyclerview library (to com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0)

The fragment I was loading had a recyclerview in it.